# Changing Translations in Liferay Portlet from Marketplace

Tags: java, liferay, portlet

I have installed an application from Liferay's Marketplace in my portal. Is it possible to change its original translations with my own ?
I know that it can be done by creating plugin to extend the orginal portlet or by manually editing the language.properties file on the server. But maybe there is a possibility to change the translations with a hook ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hooks only change the portal, not other plugins. So: Sorry, No you can't.

There is, however, a process to *build* a plugin [from another plugin](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/creating-plugins-to-extend-plugins) which is a lot better than manually changing extracted files on the server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that I need to change translations for all the portlets and hooks from the Liferay's Social Office. So in this case that means that I have to create more than 10 of these extended portlets.

Comment: Correct. That might be unpopular, but currently is the way to go. You might get away with removing all their translations. I believe that they'll now fall back to the portal's translation (which is available to hooks), but you'll have to try that.

Answer (score -1):

Sure you can write your own language hook which will extend the Liferay language.properties.

liferay-hook.xml:

```
<hook>
    <language-properties>/content/Language_en.properties</language-properties>
    <language-properties>/content/Language_fr.properties</language-properties>
    <language-properties>/content/Language_nl.properties</language-properties>
    <language-properties>/content/Language_de.properties</language-properties>
</hook>
```